# AVSpeechSynthesizer stops working

Tags: ios, ios7, avspeechsynthesizer

I have a relatively rare issue with AVSpeechSynthesizer where it'll finish speaking an utterance, but then won't speak the next one I give it. If I go to the Home screen then come back to the app, however, it'll start speaking again on its own.

It only happens maybe once every 50 - 100 runs of the app, so I can't really reproduce it to test it more thoroughly.

The `didFinishSpeechUtterance` delegate does called, but the next `didStartSpeechUtterance` does not.

I tried allocating a new instance of AVSpeechSynthesizer to see if that would fix things, but it did not.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Any ideas?

Comment: Same exact things happens to me. My usage is very basic: no delegate, no stopping. I don't queue up items at all, there is usually a natural 10 sec pause before I even call the speak method again. Did you manage to find a solution or the cause?

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing yet. Hopefully it's been fixed in iOS 8 - haven't encountered it yet, but it happened so rarely before that it's hard to say whether it actually has been fixed.

Comment: I actually found solution. It appears to be a buggy implementation of postUtteranceDelay which I had set to 0.25 before. When I don't set that at all, it appears to work every time.  I think it must be a bug in SDK where it misses the timing, and it remains in "delay" mode.